# Automatically Position Application Window Using Command File in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, putty

I'm using PuTTY to access my BSD file server and I have several terminal windows open at once. I wrote a simple command file to automate opening the terminal windows and I'd like to know if it is possible to place them at a specific location.

I have two monitors and as it is now, I have to manually drag the terminal windows over to my second monitor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do it directly from a batch file without using some 3rd party software like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

It makes it incredibly easy to move a window. For [example](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) this script would start Calculator and move it to the top-left corner:

```
Run, calc.exe
WinWait, Calculator
WinMove, 0, 0
```

You can also easily compile your script into an .exe if you want to share it with other people that don't have AHK installed. It will basically answer all your automation needs, just as it has done mine :)

Comment: I never thought I'd get an answer to this question either after two months. Thanks!