# How do I recenter the active program on Windows?

Tags: windows, center

This may seem like a silly question, but how do I recenter the active program, or get it back on my screen when I can't click it?

Sometimes when I run skype and switch between resolutions for full-screen programs, the skype window disappears off screen, and I have no way of dragging it back.

Does anyone know how to fix this without restarting the program?

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> until the desired window is active.

Try the following shortcuts:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>: Fills left half of display with active window.
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>: Fills right half of display with active window.
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>: Maximize
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>: Minimize or reset to window size prior to maximize.

**NOTE**, the above is for Windows 7. I haven't tested it on other OS's.
Not sure if it will work on earlier versions.

Comment: As alternative take a look to this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147949/automatically-position-application-window-using-command-file-in-windows